# best way to process unlimited subfloders via query string (php)

Tags: php, .htaccess, query-string

I have written a php script which loads content dynamically. I mean: when you visit mydomain.com/example , it gets rewritten by htaccess (the real url would be something like mydomain.com/index.php?example) and loads content based in the query string.

```
$page = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if (file_exists("pages/".$page.".txt") ) {
load the file and so on
}
```

But what would be the best solution to support sub-folders as well? So that you can enter mydomain.com/example/test/test2 and get the content from pages/example/test/test2? I guess this should be included in the query string, but rewritten using .htaccess.
At the moment, my htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty insecure the way you're doing it, but to the point, if you `urlencode` pages/example/test/test2 you can use it in the query string:

```
mydomain.com/pages%2Fexample%2Ftest%2Ftest2
```

Comment: Thank you! But - how does a .htaccess file look then? Why is this not secure? (Oh: I will upvote if I finally got my 15 reputation ^^ )